# Как правильно настроить путь для сохранение файла в ASP.NET (web-service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-служба

Нашел статью, где можно с помощью soap отправить на сервис кодированный файл(в моём случае jpg->base64).

Вот сам код(method):

```
[WebMethod]
    public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
    {

        try
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream
                (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/TransientStorage/") + fileName, FileMode.Create);


            ms.WriteTo(fs);

            // clean up
            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            // return OK if we made it this far
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return the error message if the operation fails
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот ссылка на статью: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-any-type-of-file-through-a-C-Sharp-web-service/

Я разархивировал её, открыл и через Postman отправил картинку, работает.
В каталоге, в папке TransientStorage появляется картинка, все ок.

Но этот метод нужно вставить в основной проект. Я вставил выше указанный код, метод появляется, папку создал в корне, отправляю картинку, показывает status "ok", но картинка в папке не появляется.
Я только начинаю, пожалуйста если можно доходчиво и понятно объясните, что и как сделать.

Comment: Посмотрите какой путь возвращает `fs.Name`. Например, так: `return "OK"+fs.Name;`

Answer (score 0):

Понял, в чем дело, может кому пригодится: 
Сначала нужно опубликовать проект, создастся отдельный каталог, вот в этом каталоге создаем нужную папку и все, работает))